# From an array of hashes, merge all array values of a specific hash key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hashmap

I have the following array:

```
[{:a => 'b', :b => ['z', 'a', ...]}, ..., {:a => 'z', :b => ['t', 'r', ...]}]
```

I would like to obtain a merged array of all array values corresponding to the key of `:b` such as this:

```
['z', 'a', 't', 'r', ... ]
```

*(`:b` will not hold any duplicates)*

I tried `reduce(&:deep_merge)`, but it didn't seem to do what I want. An answer with Rails 'magic' would be preferred, but vanilla Ruby would also be great and appreciated.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "merged array of all hash keys of `:b`". Do you mean all array values corresponding to the key `:b`?

Comment: @sawa :b is a hash key mapping to an array inside of a hash, which is part of a collection of hashes inside of an array

Comment: Dear downvoters and 'close answer' voters, I hope I have now provided a thorough explanation to my issue. I hope this answer can stay open!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`flat_map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map).

```
x = [{:a => 'b', :b => ['z', 'a']}, {:a => 'z', :b => ['t', 'r']}]
x.flat_map { |e| e[:b] }
#=> ["z", "a", "t", "r"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `each_with_object` method for it:

```
array = [{:a=>'b',:b=>['z','a']},{:a=>'z', :b=>['t','r']}]

array.each_with_object([]) do |hash, memo|
  memo.push(*hash[:b])
end
#=> ["z", "a", "t", "r"]
```

Comment: Works great, thanks you! I prefer @sschmeck's answer though since it is a bit more readable.